# Stripe doesn't verify credit card information on production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe for my Rails application with setup taken from [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe). It's working perfectly in the development mode; on production when I set up the proper credit card information (credit card number, CVC and expiration date), the amount is successfully taken from the given credit card and the required subscription is created.

But the problem is when I put into the form incorrect information and hit the "PAY" button for sending the form, it looks like the entered information are not "checked" through the Stripe API with using Javascript, but the whole form is sent out in a "usual way" (the whole page is redirected) and it ends up with showing an error message **Your card number is incorrect.**.

Why this is not handled by Stripe (it's working in the development mode)?

When I check the code, it shows that the problem is here:

```
# subscription.rb
  def save_with_payment(coupon_id)
    if valid?
      ...
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: description, 
                                           email: email, 
                                           plan: plan.plan_code, 
                                           card: stripe_card_token, 
                                           trial_end: 'now') 
      ...
```

But how is possible algorithm went into the `valid` branch if the given CVC code/expiration date is wrong?

Shouldn't this be handled by Stripe's JS API? I am on this problem the whole Saturday, but still don't have an explanation for it.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Because I entered to the form incorrect `expiration` date (or the `CVC` code). Or am I missing something?